# equivalent of --net=host in docker compose file when creating docker container

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, docker

I tried`docker run --net=host -d --name pdns-recursor pschiffe/pdns-recursor` and it works. Now my goal is to use dockerfile to pass some environment without errors.

I tried:

```
networks:
  name: host
```

and

```
networks:
  name: "host"
```

and also the examples indicated [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

I always get an `The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.recursor.networks.name contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or a null`.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Note that you say "dockerfile" but this isn't a Dockerfile but a Docker Compose file.

Comment: Yup, that was my bad I got confused. Will change it

Comment: can we do this with a Dockerfile. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode) instead:

> #### `network_mode`
>
> Network mode. Use the same values as the docker client `--network`
> parameter, plus the special form `service:[service name]`.
>
> ```
> network_mode: "bridge"
> network_mode: "host"
> network_mode: "none"
> ```

You can use `networks` to specify host networking in swarm mode, by setting the [`driver`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver-1) of a given network to `host`.

Comment: Oh, thank you sir!

Comment: can we achieve the same using a Dockerfile ?

Comment: @Noushad no, there's nothing similar in [the Dockerfile instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). It might be possible by some custom Dockerfile syntax, but I don't know of any.

Comment: @muru Alright, thanks a lot for the clarification